# how to resolve the "Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS" error in Liferay 6.2?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I am using Eclipse Kepler-4.3 and Liferay 6.2 CE GA5.

I tried to deploy a theme but I got this error:

> ```
>  [echo] Loading jar:file:/D:/FormationJEE/Liferay/LiferayGA5/tomcat/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga5/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
>  [echo] Loading jar:file:/D:/FormationJEE/Liferay/LiferayGA5/tomcat/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga5/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties
>  [echo] Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...ow-x: hidden\0/": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";"
>  [echo]                 expected at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/scss/parser.rb:1147
>  [echo]                expected! at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/script/lexer.rb:199
>  [echo]              assert_expr at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/script/parser.rb:471
>  [echo]         times_div_or_mod at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/script/parser.rb:233
>  [echo]            plus_or_minus at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/script/parser.rb:225
>  [echo]               relational at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/script/parser.rb:225
>  [echo]                eq_or_neq at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/script/parser.rb:225
>  [echo]                 and_expr at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/script/parser.rb:225
>  [echo]                  or_expr at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/script/parser.rb:225
>  [echo]                    space at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/script/parser.rb:298
>  [echo]                     expr at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/script/parser.rb:246
>  [echo]                     send at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2093
>  [echo]              assert_expr at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/script/parser.rb:470
>  [echo]                    parse at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/script/parser.rb:49
>  [echo]                     send at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2093
>  [echo]              sass_script at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/scss/parser.rb:1021
>  [echo]                   value! at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/scss/parser.rb:881
>  [echo]              declaration at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/scss/parser.rb:858
>  [echo]   declaration_or_ruleset at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/scss/parser.rb:581
>  [echo]                     call at org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270
>  [echo]                     call at org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220
>  [echo]                  rethrow at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/scss/parser.rb:1122
>  [echo]   declaration_or_ruleset at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/scss/parser.rb:591
>  [echo]              block_child at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/scss/parser.rb:553
>  [echo]           block_contents at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/scss/parser.rb:542
>  [echo]                    block at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/scss/parser.rb:534
>  [echo]                  ruleset at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/scss/parser.rb:528
>  [echo]              block_child at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/scss/parser.rb:552
>  [echo]           block_contents at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/scss/parser.rb:545
>  [echo]               stylesheet at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/scss/parser.rb:82
>  [echo]                    parse at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/scss/parser.rb:27
>  [echo]                 _to_tree at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/engine.rb:342
>  [echo]                  _render at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/engine.rb:315
>  [echo]                   render at C:/Users/MARWEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/../sass/engine.rb:262
>  [echo]                   (root) at <script>:48
>  [echo] Unable to parse /css/app.css
>  [echo] Exception in thread "main" org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (SyntaxError) Invalid CSS after
> ```
>
> "...ow-x: hidden\0/": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";"
>        [echo]   at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedEvalUnitImpl.run(EmbedEvalUnitImpl.java:127)
>        [echo]   at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runUnit(ScriptingContainer.java:1231)
>        [echo]   at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runScriptlet(ScriptingContainer.java:1224)
>        [echo]   at com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor.doEval(RubyExecutor.java:189)
>        [echo]   at com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor.eval(RubyExecutor.java:229)
>        [echo]   at com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor.eval(RubyExecutor.java:129)
>        [echo]   at com.liferay.portal.tools.SassToCssBuilder._parseSassFile(SassToCssBuilder.java:355)
>        [echo]   at com.liferay.portal.tools.SassToCssBuilder._cacheSass(SassToCssBuilder.java:186)
>        [echo]   at com.liferay.portal.tools.SassToCssBuilder._parseSassDirectory(SassToCssBuilder.java:317)
>        [echo]   at com.liferay.portal.tools.SassToCssBuilder.(SassToCssBuilder.java:172)
>        [echo]   at com.liferay.portal.tools.SassToCssBuilder.main(SassToCssBuilder.java:125)
>        [echo] Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (SyntaxError) Invalid CSS after "...ow-x: hidden\0/": expected
>   expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";"
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   D:\FormationJEE\Liferay\LiferayGA5\sdk\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common.xml:3162:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line: : The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   D:\FormationJEE\Liferay\LiferayGA5\sdk\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common.xml:1421:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line: : The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   D:\FormationJEE\Liferay\LiferayGA5\sdk\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common.xml:2866:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   D:\FormationJEE\Liferay\LiferayGA5\sdk\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common.xml:190:
>   Sass to CSS Builder generated exceptions.

Comment: So far, you have posted a statement "I have an error", but *no* information about the code that causes the error. You'll need to add more information if you want meaningful help, e.g. steps to reproduce. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ...and check https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/is-cross-posting-wrong-to-an-external-site

Answer (score 1):

May it be that you have a syntax error in the CSS

> Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...ow-x: hidden\0/": expected
>   expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";"

Comment: but in which file? I found a question with the same problem. the solution does not work for me because I already have the jar ruby-gems.jar and I do not find the file portal-ext.properties. https://web.liferay.com/fr/web/kzhang/blog/-/blogs/resolve-the-sass-syntaxerror-invalid-css-error-in-liferay-6-1

Comment: The error is in the file app.css line `overflow-x: hidden\0/; ` if I correct it and I deploy the theme, it comes back.

Comment: portal-ext.properties is a custom config file that you can provide to the portal to modify the configuration. Create a portal-ext.properties file in LIFERAY_HOME (same lvl as the tomcat folder) and put the desired configuration inside. You need to restart the server for the change to be picked up.

Comment: when you fixed the apps.css and deployed it again, did it break on the same thing? Dos your scss/scc editor support code highlighting. Are you sure that you don't have any syntax errors in the code?

Comment: I tried the Theme in other version GA1 and it works. In the file css/app.css of the **theme project** line 7837: `overflow-x: hidden\0/;` If I correct it and I deploy the theme, the same line comes back again. I have another related question that describes all the details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46890995/how-to-deploy-a-theme-in-liferay

Comment: I tried the portal-ext.properties file and It did not work for me.

Comment: By any chance did you start developing the plugin on an older version of Liferay and then continued? Did you try to delete node_modules folder and rebuild from total scratch? Liferay deps are defined as * and if you move to a newer version of Liferay it might be required to compile the theme with a newer version of the plugin. Had such a problem already. And as per @Olaf's comment could you provide more samples not only the error.

Comment: I am trying to check if my theme project is runing with the differenr version (6.2: ga1,ga2,ga3,ga4,ga5,ga6). I put the theme under the directory **sdk\ liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\themes** of each version and I tried to deploy the theme. I have different errors in the versions (GA2, GA3, GA4, GA5 and GA6).